# Apply for a cluster for scientific computing from a developing country for academic use?

Tags: application

I don't have access to a computer cluster in my university. Is there website that accepts applications for free access to a computer cluster for scientific computing?

Further information: I am in Cuba. I need something on the order of 30 processors, about 50 GB of hard drive, for a week or so. I need to run programs written in C++ and Python.

Comment: What sort of computing are interested in doing? Various different resources are available for different purposes.  For example, [EmuLab](http://www.emulab.net/) offers free cluster access for purposes of network simulation, but wouldn't be appropriate if you wanted to do, say, fluid dynamics.

Comment: This question was cross-posted to the Scicomp.SE and should probably be closed here.

Comment: @jakebeal I am doing research on metabolic networks. I need to run simulations written in Python and C++.

Comment: You may get more responses if you can give some more detail as to your situation - eg what country are you in, what sort of scale of cluster do you need, etc

Comment: @SimonW I added some more information.

Comment: BTW, not sure about US-Cuba relationships - there might be legal issues with a US organization providing massive computing power to someone in Cuba.

Comment: Yeah, the US-Cuba embargo could be a problem.  Do you have contacts in Europe, Russia, or China, where someone might be able to get you an account?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite answer the question, but in case you have *some* funds available (but not enough to buy a cluster): Various cloud services - Amazon in particular but probably others - will let you "spin up" a temporary compute cluster on their servers. You pay for this by the minute, or sometimes by more complicated systems where the price is according to demand.

For small projects this approach can be quite economical, and so may be feasible in some circumstances where access to a dedicated system is unaffordable.

Comment: There is also the chance to get a research grant from AWS or Azure, or use the trial account which GCE offers (500 USD - which allows you to at least get some initial experiments in).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't have funds.